# Nativescript Plugin for Caching

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

Is there an actively maintained nativescript plugin for data caching?

like `nativescript-cache` but sadly this plugin is now inactive.

Comment: What is the goal - what do you need to cache? The latest NativeScript modules are coming with a build-in mechanism for caching images https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/best-practices/images-optimisations#using-usecache-property

Comment: There is also the image-cache module if you need to explicitly cache some images  https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_image_cache_

Comment: @NickIliev I want to cache some data not only images for offline view and for a better user experience :)

Comment: There are a lot of ways to persist data .. e.g. using `application-settings` module or nativescript-sqlite plugin with SQLite or using nativescript-plugin-firebase with RealtimeDB and offline mode (persist property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nativescript core module `application-settings`. it does exactly same as `nativescript-cache` plugin.

```
import {
    getBoolean,
    setBoolean,
    getNumber,
    setNumber,
    getString,
    setString,
    hasKey,
    remove,
    clear
} from "application-settings";

Set and get boolean value and provide default value in case it is not set

setBoolean("isTurnedOn", true);
this.isTurnedOn = getBoolean("isTurnedOn", true);

Set and get string value

setString("username", "Wolfgang");
this.username = getString("username");

Set and get numeric value.

setNumber("locationX", 54.321);
this.locationX = parseFloat(getNumber("locationX").toFixed(3));

Reading values that are not set before while providing default value

// will return "No string value" if there is no value for "noSuchKey"
this.someKey = getString("noSuchKey", "No string value");
```

for more information you can refer nativescript docs: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/application-settings